# How to validate date coming in many format

Tags: php, date

I want to create a function to check the date date can be in many format as given below.

[image]

Here 02=Month, 2020 and 20= Year and other are dates

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
} 


ob_end_clean();

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=attendance_upload_csv'.time().'.csv');

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Expires: 0");
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$fieldArr['field_name']['agent_user_name']          = 'Agent User Name';
$fieldArr['field_name']['date_of_violation']        = 'Date Of Violation';


fputcsv($file, $fieldArr['field_name']);

fclose($file);
```

problem is its not validating all dates, please advise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I only see a single format here.. which is `d-m-Y`. Where do you see multiple formats?

Comment: @MateiMihai I don't know how to add multiple formats

Comment: @amandeep Matei means that in your sample data there is only one format. You said "date can be in many format as given below", but the dates in your sample are only in the d-m-Y format. No other formats are shown. So if you want us to understand the true problem, please give a data sample which includes all the possible formats you are trying to deal with.

Comment: To be honest though, the solution to a problem like this is usually to try and prevent dates from being sent in different formats, especially ambiguous ones, to begin with. Where is this data coming from exactly? Is it from a HTML form? You can allow users to enter dates in their local, culturally-appropriate format if you wish, but you should coerce them to a non-ambiguous format such as Y-m-d before sending to the server. Anything else should be rejected as invalid without attempting to parse it.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the reply, actually I am receiving date from CSV file and I cant change csv file

Comment: " I am receiving date from CSV file"...ok and how does that file get generated? You would hope the process which generated it used a consistent date format. If not, the solution is to fix that process. Then at least if the format is predictable, PHP can deal with it. Right now, if you believe those dates to be potentially ambiguous, there is nothing you can do to resolve it. You have to fix the source of the data. Although as I said, the examples you gave are actually all parseable as d-m-Y. It seems likely that this was the intention. It'd be strange to make a CSV with multiple formats in it

Comment: @ADyson, Please check question again I have updated how empty csv file created, the client fills the value and uploads

Comment: That extra code is irrelevant. How you create the empty CSV is unimportant to the problem. If you're letting the user put whatever they like in there, that's a bad idea. Since the data input process is out of your direct control, you need to set rules instead. Issue instructions which tell the user they must input the date in one single format (of your choosing). If they don't do that, you reject the file. Simple, problem solved. Your code cannot guess their intentions. So the solution is to tell them what is required, and then reject anything which doesn't conform to your specification.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks it's really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're letting the user put whatever they like in the incoming CSV file, that's a bad idea. Since the data input process is out of your direct control, you need to set some rules and expectations instead, which are then enforced by the PHP when it checks the uploaded file.

Issue instructions which tell the user they must input the date in one single format (of your choosing, preferably an unambiguous one such as Y-m-d, so no-one can be in any doubt what the data means when they enter it). If they don't do that, you reject the file. Simple, problem solved.

Your code cannot guess the user's intentions or what they will type. So the solution is to tell them exactly what is required, and then reject anything which doesn't conform to your specification.